# How to do Basic Auth with Axios in react

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, postman

React Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Table = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("helllllllllllllllo");

    callAPI();
  }, []);

  const callAPI = async () => {
    const url =  "some URL";
    const password = "Secret" ;
    const username = "Consumer Key";

    const data = await axios.get(
      url,
      {},
      {
        auth: {
          username: username,
          password: password,
        },
      }
    );

    console.log("data", data);
  };
  return (
   <div> Hello </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

On Postman, I go to the `Authorization` Tab and input the Username and password in their respective input fields and get the result but with axios, I getting `401` error.
Exact Error being :-

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing the auth headers. In axios [`GET`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config), first parameter is URL and second parameter is `config` object. In `config` object, you can provide `auth` property for sending [basic auth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) headers.

```
const data = await axios.get(url, {
  auth: {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  },
})
```